# MySQL Case Select not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, case, modulo

While creating a more complex stored procedure in MySQL, I encountered a weird problem with my CASE statement. I have simplified my procedure to show the issue. I am selecting three things per loop to clarify the problem: the `count` variable, the `modTemp` variable before the CASE, and then a number representing which CASE path was taken.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddPlants` (IN plantNum int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE count int;
    DECLARE modTemp int;

    SET count = 1;
    WHILE count <= plantNum DO
        SELECT CONCAT('count = ', count);
        SET modTemp = count % 3;
        SELECT CONCAT('modTemp = ', modTemp);

        CASE modTemp
            WHEN modTemp = 1 THEN
                SELECT 1;
            WHEN modTemp = 2 THEN
                SELECT 2;
            WHEN modTemp = 0 THEN
                SELECT 3;
            ELSE
                SELECT CONCAT('Error: modTemp = ', modTemp);
        END CASE;

        SET count = count + 1;
    END WHILE;
END//
```

Now I use `CALL AddPlants(3);` Here are my results:

---

**Expected output**

count = 1, modTemp = 1, 1

count = 2, modTemp = 2, 2

count = 3, modTemp = 0, 3

---

**Actual output**

count = 1, modTemp = 1, 1

count = 2, modTemp = 2, Error: modTemp = 2

count = 3, modTemp = 0, 1

---

Each time, count and modTemp are the correct values. However, on the second loop, modTemp is 2 but does not enter CASE 2. And in the third loop, modTemp is 0 but goes into CASE 1. Any ideas what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing the two ways to use `CASE`. You either write:

```
CASE
    WHEN <expression1> THEN <result1>;
    WHEN <expression2> THEN <result2>;
    ...
END CASE
```

This evaluates each expression, and executes the corresponding result for the first true one. Or:

```
CASE <expression>
    WHEN <val1> THEN <result1>;
    WHEN <val2> THEN <result2>;
    ...
END CASE
```

This compares `<expression>` to each value, and executes the corresponding result for the first one that matches.

You used the second syntax, but your values also contain a comparison. So they're all either `0` (for `false`) or `1` (for `true`), and that's what you're comparing `modTemp` to. Change to:

```
    CASE modTemp
        WHEN 1 THEN
            SELECT 1;
        WHEN 2 THEN
            SELECT 2;
        WHEN 0 THEN
            SELECT 3;
        ELSE
            SELECT CONCAT('Error: modTemp = ', modTemp);
    END CASE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be more like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddPlants` (IN plantNum int)
```

BEGIN
    DECLARE count int;
    DECLARE modTemp int;

```
SET count = 1;
WHILE count <= plantNum DO
    SELECT CONCAT('count = ', count);
    SET modTemp = count % 3;
    SELECT CONCAT('modTemp = ', modTemp);

    CASE modTemp
        WHEN 1 THEN
            SELECT 1;
        WHEN 2 THEN
            SELECT 2;
        WHEN 0 THEN
            SELECT 3;
        ELSE
            SELECT CONCAT('Error: modTemp = ', modTemp);
    END CASE;

    SET count = count + 1;
END WHILE;
```

END//